# Finding largest file size recursively from a directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a directory which contains thousands of .gz files. Now I want to find the largest uncompressed file size without unzipping it. For e.g dir1 has 1.gz,2.gz,3.gz and so on and I want to find the largest uncompressed file size without uncompressing it

I tried the following command but it is not working

```
find . -type f -name '*.gz' | xargs zcat | xargs ls -1s
```

I am new to Bash and Linux.

Comment: found a solution without any uncompressing (thanks to gzip format, which stores the original file size)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interrestingly, according to  http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html

```
ISIZE (Input SIZE)
   This contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input data modulo 2^32.
```

So the format contains the original size (modulo 2^32, which "ought to be enough for anybody", but of course is not... See warnings below!)... Now we just need a command to output it for us  : `gzip -l file(s)` : the size is the 2nd argument.

Therefore you **DO NOT NEED to uncompress** the files at all **IF** your original files were all less than 4gb in size:

```
find . -name '*.gz' -print | xargs gzip -l | awk '{ print $2, $4 ;}'  | grep -v '(totals)$' | sort -n | tail -1
```

Which will be a great deal faster than the others solutions I see here ^^

BUT **please be warned**: for files of size greater than 2^32 , the result will be only "modulo 2^32" (so for example, a file of size "2^32 + 1" bytes will be reported as having a size of 1 byte!). So if you have compressed files that were originally larger than 4Gb, you need to uncompress (on-the-fly if you want) to get their real size!

Edit: I tried to see if the ratio could be used instead of the "original size modulo 2^32" : no...

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=1_gb bs=1048576  count=1024    #creating a 1 Gb file
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=5_gb bs=1048576  count=5120    #creating a 5 Gb file
$ ls -al *gb*
-rw-r--r--    1 user  UsersGrp   1042074 Mar  4 10:30 1_gb.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 user  UsersGrp   5210215 Mar  4 10:28 5_gb.gz
$ gzip -l *gb*
compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
   1042074          1073741824  99.9% 1_gb
   5210215          1073741824  99.5% 5_gb   
   6252289          2147483648  99.7% (totals)

 (notice the 2nd: the uncompressed is not 5gb, but 1gb, as it's modulo 2^32 (=4gb) :( )
```

=> the ratio is unuseable too for files >4gb...  ( 5gb/5210215 = 1030 .  1gb/1042074 = 1030 too. So the ratio should be the same. But it seems the ratio is using the "uncompressed" field, and not the original size itself.)

Comment: I'm trying to find out if the "compressed ratio" is not limited to "modulo 2^32", and will give a more robust answer if it is not (ie, i'll use a "compressed size and ratio" to determine an approximation of the uncompressed real size)

Comment: no help from the ratio: it's computed from the 1st and 2nd field... which only allow 4 bytes to store a file size... A good workaround could have been to compute the 3rd field ("ratio") from the real compressed and uncompressed size, instead of from the 1st and 2nd field... but it's not the way they chose... (A shame... It would have had the added benefit of being able to tell if the 2nd field is the real one: if the ratio calculated from real_size/real_compressed_size matched the one from 1st/2nd field, it would mean that the 2nd field is not modulo 2^32 !)

Answer (score 2):

Your command does not really make sense; `find . -type f -name '*.gz' | xargs zcat` will (if all goes well) write out the contents of all the zip files, but it doesn't make sense to convert the contents of those files to command-line arguments (as `xargs` does) and pass them to `ls -1s` (which expects its arguments to be filenames).

I do not see a good way to salvage your approach. Instead, I recommend writing a loop:

```
max_size=0
for file in *.gz ; do
    size="$(zcat "$file" | wc -c)"
    if (( size > max_size )) ; then
        max_size="$size"
        largest_file="$file"
    fi
done
echo "$largest_file"
```

Comment: I upvoted yours, but I'm now posting a **much faster** solution : you do NOT need to uncompress at all ! (it would waste a very long time)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
find . -type f -name '*.gz' -printf '%s %p\n'|sort -nr|head -n 1
```

This will sort the *.gz files in descending order of file sizes and then print the 1st file in that list.

Comment: But the uncompressed file size is not taken into account. Otherwise very elegant.

Comment: @pitseeker You are right. This takes into account only the compressed file size.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a oneliner (over ruakh's solution) you can try this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.gz' -printf "%p "  -exec sh -c 'zcat {} | wc -c ' \; | sort -k2 | tail -1
```

Explanation:

- find the files ending with .gz
- print them
- for each file call "exec" and start a new shell that zcats the file and counts the characters
- The whole find output goes into sort and is sorted by the 2nd column (the uncompressed file size)
- 'tail -1' (e.g. just print the last (largest) filename)

Answer (score 0):

Found nearly the same solution as Olivier Dulac, at the same time, using `gzip -l`:

```
find . -name '*.gz' | xargs gzip -l | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | sort -k 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```